# Error installing Qt3D with QtCreator and qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5, qt3d

I tried installing Qt3D using QtCreator 5.1.1 on Windows 8, and I can't figure out how to succeed.

First, I followed the steps given in the documentation:

- get the sources on git://gitorious.org/qt/qt3d
- open the .pro in QtCreator
- add the "install" and "-j 3" arguments to the make command

When I build the project, I get the following error:

```
    In file included from D:\qt3D\project\qt-qt3d\src\threed\global\qglnamespace.cpp:42:0:
    D:\qt3D\project\qt-qt3d\src\threed\global\qglnamespace.h:45:29: fatal error: Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h>
                                 ^
    compilation terminated.
    Makefile.Debug:2547: recipe for target '.obj/debug_shared/qglnamespace.o' failed
    mingw32-make[3]: *** [.obj/debug_shared/qglnamespace.o] Error 1
    mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'D:/qt3D/project/release/src/threed'
    Makefile:38: recipe for target 'debug-all' failed
    mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/qt3D/project/release/src/threed'
    Makefile:40: recipe for target 'sub-threed-make_first-ordered' failed
    mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/qt3D/project/release/src'
    makefile:43: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
    mingw32-make[2]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
    mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-threed-make_first-ordered] Error 2
    mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
    15:07:03: Le processus "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" s'est terminé avec le code 2.
    Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet qt3d (kit : Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MinGW 32bit)
    Lors de l'exécution de l'étape "Make"
```

So I created the following folders into the folder "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\mingw48_32\include":

- Qt3D: I copied there all .h files located into subfolders of the src/threed folder of the qt3d sources
- Qt3DQuick: I copied there all .h files located into the src/quick3d folder of the qt3d sources

I re-run the compilation, and then I got the following errors:

```
    D:\qt3D\project\qt-qt3d\src\quick3d\qquickeffect.cpp:44:24: fatal error: qglpainter.h: No such file or directory
     #include "qglpainter.h"
                            ^
    compilation terminated.
    Makefile.Release:810: recipe for target '.obj/release_shared/qquickeffect.o' failed
    mingw32-make[3]: *** [.obj/release_shared/qquickeffect.o] Error 1
    mingw32-make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    D:\qt3D\project\qt-qt3d\src\quick3d\qquickitem3d.cpp:47:32: fatal error: qgllightparameters.h: No such file or directory
     #include "qgllightparameters.h"
                                    ^
    compilation terminated.
    D:\qt3D\project\qt-qt3d\src\quick3d\qquickmesh.cpp:44:30: fatal error: qglabstractscene.h: No such file or directory
     #include "qglabstractscene.h"
                                  ^
    compilation terminated.
    Makefile.Release:949: recipe for target '.obj/release_shared/qquickitem3d.o' failed
    mingw32-make[3]: *** [.obj/release_shared/qquickitem3d.o] Error 1
    Makefile.Release:1053: recipe for target '.obj/release_shared/qquickmesh.o' failed
    mingw32-make[3]: *** [.obj/release_shared/qquickmesh.o] Error 1
    mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'D:/qt3D/project/release/src/quick3d'
    mingw32-make[2]: *** [release-install] Error 2
    Makefile:58: recipe for target 'release-install' failed
    mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/qt3D/project/release/src/quick3d'
    Makefile:107: recipe for target 'sub-quick3d-install_subtargets-ordered' failed
    mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/qt3D/project/release/src'
    mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-quick3d-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
    makefile:55: recipe for target 'sub-src-install_subtargets' failed
    mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
    15:18:09: Le processus "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" s'est terminé avec le code 2.
    Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet qt3d (kit : Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MinGW 32bit)
    Lors de l'exécution de l'étape "Make"
```

So, I tried to copy all needed .h file into sources folders where they are needed, but I didn't work. Moreover, I think there must be another way to get what I want, but I can't see how.

I someone could help me, I would be glad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a way to succeed:

- first I downloaded the latest version of Qt, Qt 5.2.1
- I downloaded the sources of Qt3D from "git://gitorious.org/qt/qt3d" with a git client into the folder “C:\qt3d”
- with the terminal “Qt 5.2.1 for Desktop (MinGW 4.8 32 bit)”

  ```
  cd C:\qt3D
  qmake
  mingw32-make.exe install
  ```

the “install” is important so that all files are copied into Qt configuration folder.

Then, in the .pro file, add

```
QT += 3d
```

And in main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt3D 2.0
import Qt3D.Shapes 2.0
```

Lauriane